# delayed_job dies with out error - no attempt has been made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I have a delayed job which is implemented as a model method (see below).  If I use delayed_job daemon it ran and died silently.  Not one job got complete and no logged message was found.  But if I use RAILS_ENV=production rake jobs:work everything works OK.

I don't know why, even if an exception is thrown it should appear in the log, but there is none.  And if there's something wrong with the logic then why the rake job succeeded?

```
def recalc(params)
    last_known = self
    t = nil # target(self)
    target_date = self.as_on.yesterday 
    success = true
    saved = -1 
    # cater for the first one
    TimeSlot.where(employee_id:self.employee_id).where('incurred_on >= ?', self.as_on).order('incurred_on ASC').each do |ts|
        # loop
        if (ts.incurred_on >= target_date) then
            if !t.nil? && target_date.day <=7 # roll over to a new month
                t.bal_sick += 4 # add 4 days
                if t.bal_sick > 40 
                    overflow = t.bal_sick-40
                    t.bal_sick = 40
                    t.bal_sick2 += overflow
                    t.bal_sick2 = 120 if t.bal_sick2 > 120 # overflow again
                end
            end
            unless saved<0
                success = t.save 
                last_known = t
            end
            if success
                saved += 1
                t = target(last_known)
                target_date = t.as_on
            else
                logger.warn("Recalc cannot saved a record for #{t.errors.first}")
                logger.warn(t.inspect)
                return
            end
        end
        if ts.types.include? 'overtime'
            t.bal_ot += ts.hours.to_i
            t.bal_ot = 100 if t.bal_ot >100 
        elsif ts.types.include? 'toil'
            t.bal_ot -= ts.hours.to_i
        elsif ts.types.include? 'vacation'
            t.bal_vacation -= ts.hours
        elsif ts.types.include? 'sick1'
            t.bal_sick -= ts.hours
        end
    end
    logger.info("Recalc saved %d records"% saved)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems I found that I've missed out "specify your rails environment", i.e. RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start, the default environment appears to be development.

But why the default environment is development?  It should be production.  If I am in development I'd rather do rake jobs:work